# Control character in a variable for use with grep

Tags: bash

I'm looking for a way to use a variable inside a grep command to look for ctrl-character 'start of text' (x02). I know that is works with this command.

```
grep $'\x02' $FILE
```

Can anyone explain how I can put the "x02"-part in a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pattern=$'\x02'
grep "$pattern" "$file"
```

Comment: How the pattern will be if i want to check more? Like $'\x[01..31]'? I just tried several possibilities but didn't work :(